# JavaScript will not create/add elements in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have a JavaScript function that adds two Options to a select drop down list when a button is pressed. However, it only seems to work in Firefox and Chrome, not Safari.

```
function ShowNextForm()
{
    if(document.myform.Simulation[0].checked == true)
    {
        var select1 = document.getElementById('Calc_Select');
        if (select1.length == 8)
        {
            var option1a = document.createElement("Option");
            option1a.text = "NIEL (approx.) Fluence";
            option1a.value = "NIEL Fluence*";
            select1.add(option1a, select1.options[select1.length - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to add the new option before the last item in the dropdown?

Comment: If so, this works for me in the browsers your listed: http://jsfiddle.net/2mmAF/ (I didn't bother testing your code because you didn't provide a test environment)

Comment: Yes, and the newly created items are removed if a different box is checked and the length is 10. When I press the button the next from does not even load however.

Comment: Your code works for me in the same browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/8LCkE/

Comment: Oddly enough, when I changed the code from .add to .insertBefore, it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hmm well I'm not sure why `add` wasn't working for you in Safari, but I'm glad something worked for you. I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can get your code working in (all) browsers - http://jsfiddle.net/2mmAF/ , changing the code to use `insertBefore` seems to alleviate some problem you're having with Safari. Here's the code to use:

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById('Calc_Select'),
    newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.text = "NIEL (approx.) Fluence";
newOption.value = "NIEL Fluence*";

selectElement.add(newOption, selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length - 1]);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8LCkE/